# How to retrieve the internal _id of an object in a helper or event?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite, flow-router

I am trying to add a comment and it has a field of {postId}. Currently I return the post id to add it to the comment collection doing `var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');` because my route includes the id of the specific post I am going to leave a comment on in the params. Now I want to change the routes instead of myapp.com/posts/:id to myapp.com/post/:title so I can't get the id from the param anymore....how can I still get the ID of the post when it is no longer available in the router params?

So right now my event code is:

```
Template.post.events({
  "click #submitComment": function () {
      var commentText = $("#commentfield").val();
     var postId = FlowRouter.getParam('id');` 
     Comments.insert({postId: postId, comment: commentText});
  } 

})
```

I remember for other apps I used something like `template.data._id` but I can't get that to work

this questions is also for my helpers and subscriptions, I will always need to get the specific post , comment, video id of the template...but need to find a way since I don't want all my routes to include the ids on them.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing passing the template variable into the click event:

```
 "click #submitComment" : function (event, template) { ....
```

Notice the `(event, template)`. Now within the event, use  `template.data._id` as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks Nate, but still won't work, it doesn't provide any error but it won't add the template.data._id to the collection..I've tried something like that:  " "click #buttonData": function(event,template) {
    var id = template.data._id;
    Comments.insert({postId: id,});

   },"

Comment: what does logging `template.data` give you. `console.log(template.data)`

Comment: template is not defined....to retrieve the template in my app I am using {{#with posts}} {{/with}}   and the helper is return   var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
and then return Posts.findOne({_id: id})

Comment: have you logged `this` context; `console.log(this)` inside the event?

Comment: Nope, but I have on the onCreated for the subscription     var self = this;
maybe its related?

Comment: If I log this on the event then it does return the postObject...but I need to also get the objectId for the subscriptions and for the helper of Posts.find({_id: this._id}) that right now I am getting it from the queryParams but I won't be able to when I change the route style...any idea? thanks! :):)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you are changing your route from having a post's ID to having the title field instead.  It also looks like you know about #with.  Since you helper is named `posts`, here is some sample code that I think should work:

```
Template.post.helpers({
    posts() {
        var post = Posts.findOne({title: FlowRouter.getParam('title')});
        if(post) {
            return post;
        }
    }
});
```

I believe, then, that your event code can stay the same.